# non latin identifier based autocompletion

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I am using **vim** with YouCompleteMe plugin, which is awesome except the fact it has no support of unicode completion as is written [here](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/197) and [here](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/278).

I switched to vim from sublime text and i am completely excited with vim. But the fact i dont get autocompletion of words which contains (or wholly constructed) with non latin characters drives me crazy because i am writing a lot of documents in `latex` and use russian keyboard layout with vim's `langmap` option.

I dont know if there is any way to get autocompletion of my native locale (russian) words. 
I played a little with encodings and tried cp1251 as `fileencoding` and `encoding` but get no result.

Could you tell me if it is possible ? 
The default vim's complete (which is triggered by pressing `<C-x> <C-n>`) is working but it is very inconvenient to press such a long combination when you need to complete several hundreds words in a day.

I dont want any  complicated completion as i understand that it is nearly impossible with the current implementation of vim. I want identifier based completion -- complete with words that were already typed in current document.

I googled but found nothing. 
I would greatly appreciate any information related to my problem.

Here is my `.vimrc`:

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

if &diff
    " no options at all for vimdiff
else
    "=====================================================
    " Vundle settings
    "=====================================================
    " set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
    "
    set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
    call vundle#begin()

    Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'      " let Vundle manage Vundle, required


    "---------=== Code/project navigation ===-------------
    Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'            " Project and file navigation
    Plugin 'majutsushi/tagbar'              " Class/module browser


    "------------------=== Other ===----------------------
    Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround'     " Parentheses, brackets, quotes, XML tags, and more
    Plugin 'kien/ctrlp.vim'         " Convenient navigation
    Plugin 'vim-scripts/diffchanges.vim' " difchanges in file


    "--------------=== Snippets support ===---------------
    Plugin 'SirVer/ultisnips'       " Track the engine.
    Plugin 'honza/vim-snippets'     " snippets repo


    "--------------=== Completion ===---------------
    " Plugin 'Shougo/neocomplete'       " completion
    Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'     " completion
    Plugin 'shvechikov/vim-keymap-russian-jcukenmac' " alternative keymap for mac
    Plugin 'ervandew/supertab'          " man c-n to tab for compatibility YCM with UltiSnips

    "------------------=== Latex ===---------------------
    Plugin 'lervag/vim-latex'       " latex module


    "------------------=== Colors ===---------------------
    Plugin 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'   " solarized colors


    "---------------=== Languages support ===-------------
    " --- Python ---
    Plugin 'klen/python-mode'           " Python mode (docs, refactor, lints, highlighting, run and ipdb and more)
    " Plugin 'mitsuhiko/vim-jinja'      " Jinja support for vim
    " Plugin 'mitsuhiko/vim-python-combined'  " Combined Python 2/3 for Vim

    call vundle#end()                   " required



    "====================================================
    " YouCompleteMe and UltiSnip fix settings
    "=====================================================
    " show completion even in comments
    let g:ycm_complete_in_comments = 1
    let g:ycm_collect_identifiers_from_comments_and_strings = 1
    let g:ycm_collect_identifiers_from_tags_files = 1
    " set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete
    let g:ycm_filetype_blacklist = {}

    " add language keywords to list of autocomplete
    let g:ycm_seed_identifiers_with_syntax = 1
    " if one want to use ctags he should assure oneself that
    " >> ctags --version print Exuberant Ctags, see :help YouCompleteMe

    let g:ycm_key_list_select_completion=['<C-n>', '<Down>']
    let g:ycm_key_list_previous_completion=['<C-p>', '<Up>']

    let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<Tab>"
    let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<Tab>"
    let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<S-Tab>"
    let g:UltiSnipsSnippetsDir = "~/.vim/bundle/vim-snippets/UltiSnips"

    "====================================================
    " Latex settings
    "=====================================================

    " Enable latex
    let g:latex_enabled = 1
    " complete closing brace on label editing
    " let g:latex_complete_close_braces = 1
    " jump to the first error on quickfix window is open
    let g:latex_quickfix_autojump = 1
    " ignore any warnings
    let g:latex_quickfix_ignore_all_warnings = 1
    " which warnings should be ignored
    let g:latex_quickfix_ignored_warnings = [ ]
       " \ 'Underfull',
       " \ 'Overfull',
       " \ 'specifier changed to',
       " \ ]
    "  callback
    let g:latex_latexmk_callback = 1
    " set viewer and configure forward search with <leader>ls combination
    let g:latex_view_general_viewer = 'open -a Skim'
    let g:latex_view_general_viewer = '/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/MacOS/Skim'


    "====================================================
    " General settings
    "=====================================================

    " do not close files when type :e filename
    set hidden
    filetype on
    filetype plugin on
    filetype plugin indent on

    set backspace=indent,eol,start
    " aunmenu Help.
    " aunmenu Window.
    let no_buffers_menu=1
    set mousemodel=popup

    set ruler
    set completeopt-=preview
    set gcr=a:blinkon0
    if has("gui_running")
      set cursorline
    endif
    set ttyfast


    syntax on
    if has("gui_running")
    " GUI? Устанавливаем  тему и размер окна
      set background=dark
      set lines=40 columns=125
      let g:solarized_termcolors=256
      colorscheme solarized

    if has("mac")
      set guifont=Consolas:h16
      set fuoptions=maxvert,maxhorz
    else
      set guifont=Ubuntu\ Mono\ derivative\ Powerline\ 15
    endif
    else
    "  colorscheme solarized
    endif
    set switchbuf=useopen


    set enc=utf-8        " utf-8 по дефолту в файлах
    set ls=2             " всегда показываем статусбар
    set incsearch        " инкреминтируемый поиск
    set hlsearch         " подсветка результатов поиска
    set nu               " показывать номера строк
    set relativenumber   " относительная нумерация строк
    " autocmd InsertEnter * :set number
    " autocmd InsertLeave * :set relativenumber
    set scrolloff=5      " 5 строк при скролле за раз

    set ignorecase
    set smartcase     " case searching tunning

    " hide panels
    set guioptions-=m   " меню
    set guioptions-=T    " тулбар
    set guioptions-=r   "  скроллбары

    " tab tunning
    set tabstop=4
    set shiftwidth=4
    set expandtab
    set showmatch       " set show matching parenthesis
    set shiftround    " use multiple of shiftwidth when indenting with '<' and '>'
    set autoindent    " always set autoindenting on
    set copyindent    " copy the previous indentation on autoindenting

    set history=1000         " remember more commands and search history
    set undolevels=1000      " use many muchos levels of undo
    set wildignore=*.swp,*.bak,*.pyc,*.class
    set title                " change the terminal's title
    set visualbell           " don't beep
    set noerrorbells         " don't beep

   " disable colorcolumn that is set up nowhere ??
    highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=DarkGray
    " all spaces at the end of lines highlight with DarkGray color
    highlight WhitespaceEOL ctermbg=8 guibg=#073642
    match WhitespaceEOL /\s\+$/
    " delete all spaces at the end of lines
    autocmd BufWritePre * :%s/\s\+$//e


    "----------=========  Folding ==========------------

    " remap keys zj an zk to jump to next closed fold
    nnoremap <silent> <leader>zj :call NextClosedFold('j')<cr>
    nnoremap <silent> <leader>zk :call NextClosedFold('k')<cr>
    function! NextClosedFold(dir)
        let cmd = 'norm!z' . a:dir
        let view = winsaveview()
        let [l0, l, open] = [0, view.lnum, 1]
        while l != l0 && open
            exe cmd
            let [l0, l] = [l, line('.')]
            let open = foldclosed(l) < 0
        endwhile
        if open
            call winrestview(view)
        endif
    endfunction

    "folding settings
    " set foldmethod=indent   "fold based on indent
    " set foldnestmax=10      "deepest fold is 10 levels
    " set nofoldenable        "dont fold by default
    " set foldlevel=1         "this is just what i use
    " toggle fold with space rather then inconvenient za
    "nnoremap <space> za

    " highlight text on dark when exceeding 80 column
    augroup vimrc_autocmds
        autocmd!
        autocmd FileType ruby,python,javascript,c,cpp highlight Excess ctermbg=DarkGrey guibg=Black
        autocmd FileType ruby,python,javascript,c,cpp match Excess /\%80v.*/
        autocmd FileType ruby,python,javascript,c,cpp set nowrap
    augroup END

    " show NERDTree on F1 pressed
    map <F1> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
    " ignore theese extensions
    let NERDTreeIgnore=['\~$', '\.pyc$', '\.pyo$', '\.class$', 'pip-log\.txt$', '\.o$']

    " set switching to Russian keyboard by pressing C-^
    " the combination is awful but it is default and we will use it
    " set keymap=russian-jcukenmac
    " " the option for being able to press CTRL-N or CTRL-P to complete from
    " set iminsert=0
    " set imsearch=0
    " highlight lCursor guifg=NONE guibg=Cyan
    " задаём проверку правописания
    set langmap=йq,цw,уe,кr,еt,нy,гu,шi,щo,зp,х[,ъ],фa,ыs,вd,аf,пg,рh,оj,лk,дl,э'
    set langmap+=яz,чx,сc,мv,иb,тn,ьm,ю.,ЙQ,ЦW,УE,КR,ЕT,НY,ГU,ШI,ЩO,ЗP,Х{,Ъ},ФA,ЫS
    set langmap+=ВD,АF,ПG,РH,ОJ,ЛK,ДL,ЯZ,ЧX,СC,МV,ИB,ТN,ЬM,Ж:,Б<,Ю>,]`,[~
    set langmap+=\\;*,\\,^


    set spelllang=ru_ru,en_us
    " get suggestions on spelling
    set complete+=kspell
    " check spell by default
    set spell

    " <Ctrl-l> redraws the screen and removes any search highlighting.
    nnoremap <silent> <C-l> :nohl<CR><C-l>


    " wrap long lines to the new lines
    set wrap
    " do not break words in the middle
    set linebreak

    "====================================================
    " Here would be useful comments on how vim executes,
    " behaves, some useful features, links, etc.
    "=====================================================
    "
    " 1. To see where all keymaps appears to be on the FS:
    "    :echo globpath(&rtp, "keymap/*.vim")
    " 2. See all mappings: :help index
    "
    "



endif
```

Comment: You could make a custom mapping like `inoremap <key> <C-x><C-o>` but… are you *really* sure you need 3 completion engines? Also, Supertab should already do what you want.

Comment: Supertab  allows only to define shortcut for such a combination, if i am not wrong.  What i am asking for is as-you-type completion.